# Reading a file on aws s3 with a Java lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

**CONTEXT :**

I am trying to read a csv file on AWS s3, compute its data and write the results on another csv in the same s3 bucket.

I tried the following code to create a class that would read my `Main`, with arguments stored in a text file named `lambdaCmd.txt`. Each time `lambdaCmd.txt` is modified, the lambda function is triggered and the content of `lambdaCmd.txt` is passed to the following class via the `s3event` parameter :

```
public class LambdaCmd implements RequestHandler<S3Event, Void>{

    static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(LambdaCmd.class);

    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(S3Event s3event, Context context) {

        //Getting my txt file's path
        S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord record = s3event.getRecords().get(0);
        String bkt = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();
        String key = record.getS3().getObject().getKey().replace('+', ' ');
        try {
            key = URLDecoder.decode(key, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex);
        }

        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

        try {

            //Getting my text file as a String Stream
            InputStreamReader cmdStream =
                new InputStreamReader(s3Client.getObject(bkt, key).getObjectContent());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(cmdStream);

            //Parsing the command in cmdStream
            //...
            //The command is now "String[] cmdArray" to be passed to my main

            MyMain.main(cmdArray);
            //The main function reads and write from s3 with a similar use of s3Client

            br.close();

        } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException ex) {
            LOGGER.error(ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM :**

After logging some debug messages in this code, I figured out that the lambda function stops at this line :

```
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

Here is the CloudWatch log (I hide personal information with `##########`):

```
START RequestId: ########## Version: $LATEST
16:12:11.596 [main] DEBUG path.to.mylambdaclass.LambdaCmd - LambdaCmd started
16:12:11.616 [main] DEBUG path.to.mylambdaclass.LambdaCmd - Just before creating s3Client
END RequestId: ##########
REPORT RequestId: ##########    Duration: 12398.45 ms   Billed Duration: 12400 ms Memory Size: 128 MB   Max Memory Used: 67 MB
```

I also have a log message just after creating `s3Client`, but it is not printed in logs.

**QUESTION :**

Why is my lambda ending prematurely? Do I misuse some objects?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap that statement in a `try` block?  At a guess the Lambda doesn't have the correct permissions but logging the output from any exceptions thrown would be helpful.

Comment: I just tried it, it does not change anything. I gave the lambda admin permissions, it was already an issue that I resolved earlier.

Comment: in the try catch, what does the error say?
Also did you packae the lambda function with the correct jars?

Comment: I caught `Exception` to catch any of its subclasses, with a simple error log. I packaged the function with maven shade plugin and all the needed dependencies from AWS.

Comment: The error is not printed in logs, this is what puzzles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding the following try/catch wrapping all the code in `handleRequest` method (I was not catching Errors, this is why I did not see it) :

```
try {
    //My code above
} catch (Error | Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e);
}
```

I got a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. I had set the lambda memory to 128MB since my code in local was working with less than that. But it seems that reading from s3 needs a bit more and now it works fine with 512MB.